# SFF Short story anthology: girl named Willow restores planets, and unicorns create balance in the environment

Tags: story-identification, generation-ship, unicorns, anthology-book

Looking for the title of a short story and the anthology it appeared in.

The one story it contained had a girl named Willow(?) on a generation ship and she was training to be a restorer (someone who terraforms and ecologically restores planets).

One of her friends' got in trouble for creating bumblebees and part of her project had unicorns in it because the unicorns created balance in the environment.

Comment: There’s a possibility that this short story might be in more than one anthology. Are you looking for the story, or the anthology? If the latter, can you remember anything about the other stories therein?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is "[Stranded](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stranded-Anne-Bishop/dp/1611941660)" (2012) by Anne Bishop.

> The Restorers travel the universe fulfilling a purpose handed down
> through the generations. They live and die aboard city-ships, never
> knowing the worlds they create and save. What begins as a disastrous
> training exercise in creating and balancing ecosystems becomes an
> unexpected fight for survival. The only hope may be the secret project
> of an untried Restorer team.
>
> <sub><sup>**Official Blurb**</sup></sub>

---

> *Willow lives on city-ship that travels around the galaxy. The crew's
> mission (which carries quasi-religious overtones) is the restoration
> of devastated worlds (sort of like playing SimPlanet). Although she is
> merely a student, Willow mysteriously becomes responsible for
> restoring an entire island. Apart from an unfortunate bit of silliness
> involving unicorns, the story becomes interesting when it focuses on
> the restoration work, the careful balancing of plants and birds and
> bees, predators and prey.*
>
> <sub><sup>[**TChris Amazon Review**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stranded-Anne-Bishop/dp/1611941660)</sup></sub>